# Should "use" statement generally reference a [fully qualified] class or a namespace?

Tags: php

There are lots of articles that describe how to use namespaces in PHP-5.3+ I am particularly interested in the conventions in the `use` statement.

What most articles dot not point out, is that `use` can reference a namespace or a class. So to reference my class in PSR-0 location Foobar/Helper/Helper.php I can either do this:

```
use \Foobar\Helper; // This is a namespace
class Whatever {
    ...
    Helper\Helper::MyHelperMethod();
```

or this:

```
use \Foobar\Helper\Helper; // This is a class
class Whatever {
    ...
    Helper::MyHelperMethod();
```

No packages I have seen document which they are using on each `use` statement, and that can often lead to guesswork.

So, is it bad practice to use one approach or the other? Or perhaps to mix the concepts? Or is it perhaps just one of those things people rarely document?

Or maybe I am just misunderstanding the whole issue?

Comment: If both works, I think it depends on whether you want to get just one class from the namespace, or many. If many, then go ahead and include the whole namespace, otherwise it'd only cause confusion and maybe slow things down.

Comment: Okay, so use whichever narrows down the context the most; both are good. I guess everybody else are using IDEs that tell them whether the alias is for a class or a namespace, and so never need to document it. If I just look at the file with an editor, there are few clues. And it is that which left me unsure about how people where using "use".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a namespace `\Foobar\Helper`, then

```
use \Foobar\Helper;
```

allows you to access *all* classes from the `\Foobar\Helper` namespace with `Helper` as a  namespace qualifier. The line

```
use \Foobar\Helper\Helper;
```

gives you more control over what classes you want to access without the namespace qualifier. On the other hand, it is quite tedious to keep the `use` declarations in sync with the code during development. On the third hand, it servers as a documentation about what dependencies exist in the file.

To distinguish whether a `use` statement refers to a namespace or a class, an IDE such as Eclipse PDT helps.

Comment: Good point about the IDE. I tend not to use an IDE, so rely on the documentation people leave in the code, which tends to be sparse these days (presumably because *they* are using an IDE).

Answer (score 2):

The point of `use` is to reduce repeatedly typing the same fully qualified class name. It allows you to produce shorter, more readable code. It depends on your situation which is *the most* readable way to write your code. If you just need one class from a namespace, you can alias it directly. If you need a lot of classes from one namespace, it may make the most sense to alias only up to the namespace. If several classes from separate namespaces are similarly named, it can make code clearer if you only alias up to the namespace. It's entirely up to you and the situation.

Comment: The fact that a class can be aliased in this way is actually new to me. I always thought it was just a namespace that could be "used" and/or aliased, and not a fully-qualified class name. None of the tutorials I have found spell this out in a simple statement. Live and learn :-)